# React MUI Menu does not close

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm doing some practice with material on react but i've encountered a problem with menu.

The weird thing is that i have two IconButton components,
if I put the onClick that set the anchor element on the first IconButton, all works well.

If I put the onClick that set the anchor element on the second IconButton, the menu will never close..

why it happens? and how to solve it?
here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';

import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import AccountIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';

function TopComp(props) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleMenuClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
            //onClick={(event) => handleMenuClick(event)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="end"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="menu"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }}
              onClick={(event) => handleMenuClick(event)}
            >
              <Menu
                id="basic-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={isMenuOpen}
                onClose={handleMenuClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
              <Avatar>
                <AccountIcon />
              </Avatar>
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TopComp;
```

Comment: **Hey check my answer, I tried it on codesandbox, and its working. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70644267/14781260**

Answer (score 5):

Put your `Menu` component out of the `IconButton`s :-

```js
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';

import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import AccountIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';

function TopComp(props) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleMenuClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
            onClick={(event) => handleMenuClick(event)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <Menu
            id="basic-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={isMenuOpen}
            onClose={handleMenuClose}
           >
             <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
             <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
             <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>

          <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="end"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="menu"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }}
              onClick={(event) => handleMenuClick(event)}
            >
              <Avatar>
                <AccountIcon />
              </Avatar>
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TopComp;
```

[**On codesandbox.io**](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-glitter-o4mjr?file=/src/TopComp.js)

Comment: Thanks for this. It does seem to matter where your `<Menu>` is located.

Comment: Works like a champ.